# Umbrella term for mustard, ketchup and others

Tags: word-request

Is there a generic umbrella term that can be used for anything liquid that is added to, for example, a Subway hamburger? That is, mustard, ketchup, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Sauce' works:

> 1: a condiment or relish for food
>   *especially*: a fluid dressing or topping

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sauce))

Both examples you mention, mustard and ketchup, are listed on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauce).